# session.abandon is not generating new session

Tags: asp.net, session

I am using asp.net 3.5

`Session.Abandon()` is not using the new `SessionId`.

```
Session["abc"] = "abc";
Session.Abandon(); //Session id is same as checked in add watch
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and this is by design.  It will reuse the same session ID.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918

Also

http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/04/26/asp-net-session-state-revisited.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can `Session.IsNewSession` to identify wether the sesiion is new one or not instead of using the `SessionId`, ASP.net reuses `SessionId`, as suggested [in the KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918) you can get around this by programmatic-ally setting the `SessionId` to null in the client side cookies.

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
```

Comment: Response.Redirect(Request.Path); IS ALSO REQUIRED TO ADD AS A FINAL LINE.

Answer (score 2):

`Session.Clear()` then the session variables clear up but the user remaining in the same session (if you don't want him to relogin for example) and reset all his session specific data.

`Session.Abandon()` only takes effect after page is completely executed. So the current page that called Abandon still has that same session. All next browser calls will be on a new Session.i.e You lose that specific session and the user will get a new session key.